# keep check box values until click the submit

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

i need to build the questions paper with true/false answers.every question have 5 answers.like a, b, c, d and e.

before submit , student click the check box for each answer.when i click the submit button finally, i need to send the whole answers for the database table.

please let me know , how to keep values until submit.

My sample code,

```
 <script>
    function sendReq(x,y) 
    { 
        var answer_id   = $("input[name=answer]").val();                                
        $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: 'test_submit.php', 
            data: { qid: x, pid: y,aid: answer_id },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#answer_response").html(data);   
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
 <script>
    function clickCheckbox(){

        var checkedValue = null; 
        var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('messageCheckbox');
        for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
            if(inputElements[i].checked){
                checkedValue = inputElements[i].value;
                $("#answer").val(checkedValue);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                $("#answer").val(null);
            }

        }
    }
 </script>

 <ul class="list6">
 <?php
    include('config/config2.php');                                      

    $rec_limit = 1;
    $query = "SELECT count(question_id) FROM question WHERE paper_id='".$paperid."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(! $result )
    {
          die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
    } 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM );
    $rec_count = $row[0];
    if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
    {
         $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
         $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
    }
    else
    {

         $page = 0;
         $offset = 0;

    }
        $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);

    if( isset($_GET{'prnt'} ) )
    {
        if($rec_count>(($page+1)* $rec_limit))
            $prnt=($page+1)* $rec_limit." of ".$rec_count;
        else
            $prnt=$rec_count." of ".$rec_count;
    }
    else
    {
        if($rec_count>$rec_limit)
            $prnt=$rec_limit." of ".$rec_count;
        else
            $prnt=$rec_count." of ".$rec_count;
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE paper_id='".$paperid."' LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query );
    if(! $result )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());

    }



        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<form action='' method='post' onsubmit='myButton.disabled = true; return true;'>";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM answer");

            if($row['paper_id'] == $paperid){
                echo '<li>' .$row['question'].'</li>';
                $question_id;
                $paper_id;

                        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                        {

                            if($row['question_id'] == $row2['question_id']){
                                $question_id = $row['question_id'];


                                $scheme = $row['scheme_id'];

                                $query_scheme = "SELECT * FROM mark_scheme WHERE scheme_id='".$scheme."'";
                                $result_scheme = mysqli_query($con, $query_scheme );

                                $row_scheme = mysqli_fetch_array($result_scheme);

                                if($row_scheme['type_id'] == 1){
                                    $answer_id = $row2['answer_id'];
                                    $paper_id = $row2['paper_id'];

                                    echo '<li><input type="radio" id="answer_id_group" name="answer_id" value="'.$answer_id.'" onchange="getRadioValue();">'.$row2['answer'].'</li>';

                                }

                                else {
                                    $answer_id = $row2['answer_id'];
                                    $paper_id = $row2['paper_id'];
                                    echo '<li><input type="checkbox" id="answer_id_group" class="messageCheckbox" name="chb[]" value="1" onclick="clickCheckbox()">True<input type="checkbox" id="answer_id_group" class="messageCheckbox" name="chb[]" value="0" onclick="clickCheckbox()">False   <input type="hidden" id="answer_id_group" name="chb[]" value="'.$answer_id.'">'.$row2['answer'].'</li>';

                                }
                            }

                        }
                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="email_group" name="email" value="'.$email.'">';

                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="paper_id" name="paper_id" value="'.$paper_id.'">';
                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="question_id" name="question_id" value="'.$question_id.'">';

                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="question_id_group" name="question_id" value="'.$row['question_id'].'">';

                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="answer" name="answer" value="">';
                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="paper_id_group" name="paper_id" value="'.$row['paper_id'].'">';


                        $already_submitted = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student_answer WHERE user='".$email."' AND question_id='".$question_id."' AND type=1");

                        if(mysqli_num_rows($already_submitted))
                        {
                            echo '<style>#submit_answer{ display: none;}</style>';

                        }else{

                        }

                        echo '<li><input type="submit" name="myButton" value="Submit" class="user-btn" id="submit_answer" onclick="return sendReq('.$question_id.','.$paper_id.');"></li>';

                        echo '<br><br>';

            }
            echo "</form>";

        }


        if( $page == 0 )
        {
         echo $prnt." |";
        echo "<a href=\"?page=$page&prnt=$prnt\">"; echo "Next >>"; echo"</a>";
    $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);

    if( isset($_GET{'prnt'} ) )
    {
    if($rec_count>(($page+1)* $rec_limit))
    $prnt=($page+1)* $rec_limit." of ".$rec_count;
    else
    $prnt=$rec_count." of ".$rec_count;
    }
    else
    {
    if($rec_count>$rec_limit)
    $prnt=$rec_limit." of ".$rec_count;
    else
    $prnt=$rec_count." of ".$rec_count;
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE paper_id='".$paperid."' LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query );
    if(! $result )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());

    }



        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<form action='' method='post' onsubmit='myButton.disabled = true; return true;'>";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM answer");

            if($row['paper_id'] == $paperid){
                echo '<li>' .$row['question'].'</li>';
                $question_id;
                $paper_id;

                        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
                        {

                            if($row['question_id'] == $row2['question_id']){
                                $question_id = $row['question_id'];


                                $scheme = $row['scheme_id'];

                                $query_scheme = "SELECT * FROM mark_scheme WHERE scheme_id='".$scheme."'";
                                $result_scheme = mysqli_query($con, $query_scheme );

                                $row_scheme = mysqli_fetch_array($result_scheme);

                                if($row_scheme['type_id'] == 1){
                                    $answer_id = $row2['answer_id'];
                                    $paper_id = $row2['paper_id'];

                                    echo '<li><input type="radio" id="answer_id_group" name="answer_id" value="'.$answer_id.'" onchange="getRadioValue();">'.$row2['answer'].'</li>';

                                }

                                else {
                                    $answer_id = $row2['answer_id'];
                                    $paper_id = $row2['paper_id'];
                                    echo '<li><input type="checkbox" id="answer_id_group" class="messageCheckbox" name="chb[]" value="1" onclick="clickCheckbox()">True<input type="checkbox" id="answer_id_group" class="messageCheckbox" name="chb[]" value="0" onclick="clickCheckbox()">False   <input type="hidden" id="answer_id_group" name="chb[]" value="'.$answer_id.'">'.$row2['answer'].'</li>';

                                }
                            }

                        }
                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="email_group" name="email" value="'.$email.'">';

                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="paper_id" name="paper_id" value="'.$paper_id.'">';
                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="question_id" name="question_id" value="'.$question_id.'">';

                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="question_id_group" name="question_id" value="'.$row['question_id'].'">';

                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="answer" name="answer" value="">';
                        echo '<input type="hidden" id="paper_id_group" name="paper_id" value="'.$row['paper_id'].'">';


                        $already_submitted = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM student_answer WHERE user='".$email."' AND question_id='".$question_id."' AND type=1");

                        if(mysqli_num_rows($already_submitted))
                        {
                            echo '<style>#submit_answer{ display: none;}</style>';

                        }else{

                        }

                        echo '<li><input type="submit" name="myButton" value="Submit" class="user-btn" id="submit_answer" onclick="return sendReq('.$question_id.','.$paper_id.');"></li>';

                        echo '<br><br>';

            }
            echo "</form>";

        }


        if( $page == 0 )
        {
         echo $prnt." |";
        echo "<a href=\"?page=$page&prnt=$prnt\">"; echo "Next >>"; echo"</a>";


        }
        else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
        {

           $last = $page - 2;
           echo "<a href=\"?page=$last&prnt=$prnt\"> "; echo "<< Last"; echo"</a>";

        }
        else if( $page > 0 )
        {
           $last = $page - 2;

           echo "<a href=\"?page=$last&prnt=$prnt\">"; echo "<< Last"; echo"</a> |";
           echo " ".$prnt." |";
           echo "<a href=\"?page=$page&prnt=$prnt\">"; echo "Next >>"; echo"</a>";

        }
    ?>
    </ul>
    <div id="answer_response" class="answer-box"></div>
```

please, anyone can help me solving this problem ?

Comment: You should at least put some effort in formatting your code to make it readable. You could also add a fiddle to show what you've achieved until now.

Answer (score 0):

if there are multiple checkboxes then you can not use id of checkbox as id will only consider the first element to get all the checked values use class. give same class name to all checkboxes and get the selected checkbox or radio button value using the following selector

```
$("input[name=answer]:checked").val()
```